# How can I create database models across all the databases specified into "SQLALCHEMY_BINDS" and default database as well using flask sqlalchemy binds

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

```
engine = db.get_engine(current_app, bind=tenant_name)
session_maker = db.sessionmaker()
session_maker.configure(bind=engine)
session = session_maker()
```

I am trying to use the above code to get the session, but I am not able to create tables into all the databases.

Answer (score 0):

From the Flask-SQLAlchemy [documentation](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/binds/#creating-and-dropping-tables):

> The [`create_all()`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.create_all) and [`drop_all()`](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.drop_all) methods by default operate on all declared binds, including the default one

`db.create_all()` will create tables from your model classes that subclass `db.Model`.

You need an active application context to do this. Inside your application factory function, or wherever you're initializing your database with `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` call or `db.init_app(app)`, create your tables like this:

```
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```